# Mysql - selecting distinct if not null

Tags: mysql, distinct

I need to give my client the option to publish some posts with same name in different categories. the CMS is closed and I can't add anymore fields... 
There is a spare field which I can use to identify posts as identical, but I don't won't a situation where to exact posts will load (posts in my case are images).

So I figured my client can specify identical "field" for all identical posts.

The problem is that the default for the field is null. if i'll use distinct, only one result will come from all the non-identical posts (all of them by default = null)...

Is there a way to select distinct "field" if not null?

I tried looking and trial and error with the above but it didn't work for me...

The query itself is quite simple...

```
SELECT id,introtext,publish_up,publish_down 
from #__content 
WHERE catid IN(936,937,940,959,972,988,991) AND state = 1 
  AND ( publish_up = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR publish_up <= "2011-10-30 12:12:59" )
  AND ( publish_down = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR publish_down >= "2011-10-30 12:12:59" ) 

--removed duplicated query
```

Will appreciate any clue or directions... 
Thanks!
Yanipan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Which field is by default NULL? I'll just name it X and you can change it accordingly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id,introtext,publish_up,publish_down,IFNULL(X,id) AS distinct_field 
from #__content 
WHERE catid IN(936,937,940,959,972,988,991) AND state = 1 
AND ( publish_up = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR publish_up <= "2011-10-30 12:12:59" )
AND ( publish_down = "0000-00-00 00:00:00" OR publish_down >= "2011-10-30 12:12:59" )
```

I hope I got it right!

Comment: Looks great. never heard on IFNULL but i guess you learn something new every day :) i'll try it asap (when i get to the office) and let you know how it went. thanks!

Comment: OK, It kinda works, but the result are not distinct, meaning I get the field distinct_field if its not null, but it still gets a row for each one in the DB, even with the same distinct field... I need only one from each of the distinct_field which is not null...

Comment: You do not want any rows with introtext field value NULL?

Comment: I want all of them, but if its not null, I want only one of each value... So if I have 10 null, I have them all, and if I have four more, two with 'xyz' and two with 'qwe', I only want one of each... I tried distinct before but it still gave me all of them... Thanks again for your time and effort...

Comment: OK, I tried it again once more to be sure and it works now :) - SELECT DISTINCT IFNULL(created_by_alias,id). Thanks so much for the help!

Answer (score 2):

```
select introtext from #__content group by introtext where introtext is not null;
```

Comment: A small mistake here: WHERE goes before GROUP BY

Comment: sorry, any chance you can explain how the grouping can replace the distinct? I'm not getting this exactly... thank you for the reply!